# Java, coding right click functionality into the desktop

Tags: java, image, operating-system, right-click, file-management

I am working on a project using Java 8.  Most of it involves gathering and managing lots of images. I want the user to be able to right click on an image in any folder, on the desktop, or even in a web page and for the right click menu that comes up to include a "Transfer to Database" option such that the user can send the image along with any additional details he or she might enter to a database ( or to a menu with options for handling the transfer).  It should work for multiple selections as well.

Is it possible to do this in Java? I wasn't able to come up with anything in a google search and I kind of suspect this will involve some windows specific programming - a topic I know little about.  I will also need to use a java program installation/deployment spackage. If a completely Java answer is impossible I'd appreciate any advice regarding a solution and how to integrate it with my existing java code.

Thank your for your help,

Marc

Comment: what are you supposed to use? swing, javafx, whatever you want...?

Comment: Whatever I choose, preferably JavaFx although I do have some Swing experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To integrate this in browsers, the best way would be to look into *add ons*, for example [for Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons). Here you have to use the specific language and framework of the browser, for Firefox it's Javascript.

For the Windows Explorer, it's called [shortcut menu handlers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144171(v=vs.85).aspx). The handler program itself can be any Windows executable, so it's possible to implement the logic in Java.

Comment: aha, yes, thats the term I was groping for :)